# How to install xset?

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, monitor

I can't execute 'xset' program. How to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 server?

```
juldou@ubuntu-asus-server:~$ xset dpms force off
-bash: xset: command not found
```

Comment: apt-get install x11-xserver-utils should do the trick?

Comment: definitely yes.

Comment: @vidarlo you can post that as an answer imho :)